# How to Input an IP address and print the next numbers in the series

Tags: python, python-3.7

Very new to programming and learning the basics. The code should allow the user to input an IP address, and then print the next five IP Addresses. The instructions for the assignment are as follows: Write a python program to read four numbers (representing the four octets of an IP) and print the next five IP address. You do not need to validation the numbers are true IP addressing schemas. I am looking for sequential addition through looping.

The Code I have so far is:

```
 import ipaddress
 int(ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.255.252'))
 start_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.168.255.253')
 end_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address('192.169.0.2')
 for ip_int in range(int(start_ip), int(end_ip)):
     print(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip_int))
```

Rather than the IP Address being known I should be able to enter it and then have it print the next 5 addresses. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You’re only asking how to take user `input()`…?

Comment: Correct. luigigi's answer solved my question, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ip = input("Input IP address:")
import ipaddress
start_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip))+1)
end_ip = ipaddress.IPv4Address(int(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip))+6)
for ip_int in range(int(start_ip), int(end_ip)):
    print(ipaddress.IPv4Address(ip_int))
```

Output after inputing `192.168.255.253`:

```
192.168.255.254
192.168.255.255
192.169.0.0
192.169.0.1
192.169.0.2
```

Comment: Thank you Luigigi. How would  I modify this code to not show the start_ip but just the 5 addresses after? This was very helpful, thank you

Comment: I edited the answer. Just increment the start_ip by 1

Comment: Thank You for the quick reply, figured it out. I appreciate it.